# Issue with images in CollectionView/TableView loaded from server, doesnt load in each cell immediately

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, uicollectionview

I have this strange issue when i load images from Parse-Server via simple queries.

I have this class called "Recipes" and there i have these columns.

- name (string)
- image (file)

  etc.

So this is my code to load the recipes from that class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 queryRecipes("")
}


func queryRecipes(searchText:String) {

self.recipesArray.removeAllObjects()
    
    
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Recipes")
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error)-> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.recipesArray = NSMutableArray(array: objects!)
            // Reload CollView
            self.recipesCollView.reloadData()
            self.view.hideHUD()
                        
            // Hide/show the nothing found Label
            if self.recipesArray.count == 0 {     self.nothingFoundLabel.hidden = false
            } else { self.nothingFoundLabel.hidden = true }
            
        } else {
            print(error)
        } }
        

}
```

And then the collection view code

```
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recipesArray.count
    }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("RecipesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RecipesCell
    
    var recipesClass = PFObject(className: "Recipes")
    recipesClass = recipesArray[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
    cell.titleLabel.text = "\(recipesClass["name"]!)"

let imageFile = recipesClass["image"] as? PFFile
cell.coverImage.file = imageFile
cell.coverImage.loadInBackground(nil)
   cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    
return cell
}
```

And inside the cell file i have the following

```
import UIKit
import ParseUI

class RecipesCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    /* Views */
    @IBOutlet weak var coverImage: PFImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
}
```

And from the main.storyboard inside the image view i have set this class.
[image]

So the issue is that i have 10 images.
When i go to the certain view it shows the first 4 that i can see them in my phone it loads them good. But when i scroll down to see more in the next 6 cells it shows for example

5th cell -> image of the 1st cell and then the image of the 5th cell.
6th cell -> random image of one of the other cells and it goes on.

BUT when i refresh i dont see any of this reaction.

Does anyone have any idea of why is this happening??
I think my code is legit but i'm missing something.

Thanks for your time.

PS, This happens also for the tableview.

PS2. I have also tried this. Inside storyboard i have set a static image to the uiimage, but it still makes this thing that loads different images and then the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cells are being reused, that means that when you dequeue one it might come back with other data in it (it is already instantiated and now it is reused). So you basically need to do a "cleanup" before presenting it.

The same thing happens for the text but because it's not loading from a server or anything you can't see it on screen happening.

So what you need to do is set the image to a placeholder image

```
cell.coverImage.image = UIImage(named:"placeholder")
```

right before this line:

```
cell.coverImage.file = imageFile
```

I hope that helps. :)

Comment: this is working great. Cause it shows first one image that i have in my assets and then it loads the other one. and i think its the proper UX design for any app.

Answer (score 2):

It all happens because the cells are reused.

1. Cells are reused, so you need to clear it/set it to default, before you reuse it.

2. Cells are reused and scrolling can be faster than fetching the image from the server: *so wrong completion callback can happen for the wrong cell!*. When the image finishes loading you need to check if the cell should still load the image, or was it reused in the meantime (this means it's loading another image - so it can cause the image flash you mentioned).

```
let imageFile = recipesClass["image"] as? PFFile
cell.coverImage.image = nil // 1. Clearing the cell
// or as in Abavisg's answer you load the default image instead of nil
cell.coverImage.file = imageFile

// This is kind of pseudocode as I'm not familiar with the Parses' API
cell.coverImage.loadInBackground() { loadedImage in
   // 2. Here you have to check if the loadedImage is the right image 
   // for the cell
   if ( loadedImage.imageFile == imageFile) {
    //loadTheImage
   } else {
    //skipLoadingTheImage -> The cell was reused
   }
}
```